# android - how to upload an image to dropbox?

Tags: android, image, upload, dropbox

I am using the dropbox api, but can't figure out how to upload image, i keep getting file not found exception even when i browse for the image.

I get the image url like this ( i used a browse method to find the picture so the picture definitely exists)
here uri.getPath() is the path to the image and looks like this for example:
"/external/images/media/536"

```
protected void photoToPostChosen(Uri uri){
    Uri photoUri = uri;
    String id = photoUri.getLastPathSegment();
    if(null != id){
        //Bitmap thumbBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(id), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        EditText imagetextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UI_txt_image_name);
        imagetextbox.setText(uri.getPath());


    }
}
```

then i use this code to upload it to dropbox, but it keeps giving me file not found.

```
    // Uploading content.
    mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("User_info_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imgpath = mySharedPreferences.getString("TEXT_IMAGELOCATION_KEY", "test");
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        Uri path = Uri.parse(imgpath);
        File file = new File(path.toString());
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/testing.txt", inputStream,
                file.length(), null, null);
        Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
    } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
        // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
        Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know if something is wrong with the code?

Comment: You'd better to use `e.printStackTrace()`, other than `Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");`, which just tells you something wrong, not the root exception.

Comment: i tried, it mainly says no such file or directory, i dont understand the other lines of text.

Comment: So paste the exception to let people know what happended

Answer (score 0):

did you add the permission in your xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```